Efficient Imputation method for big longitudinal dataset in R
I have very big dataset of around 3 million rows and 50 variables of different types. The dataset is longitudinal in long format (around 350 000 unique individuals). I want to impute missing data while taking into account the longitudinal nature of the data nested within individuals. My initial thought was multiple imputation with predictive mean matching on 2 levels. (mice package with auxilary package miceadds and 2l.pmm), however not only does the imputation take days to complete but then the post-imputation analysis with pooling results from multiple datasets is pretty much impossible even for a high end desktop (64GB DDR5, i9).I also tried random forests with missForests (ID is used as predictor which i believe does not really account for nested data), and doParallel but even for a small subset of 10 000 rows, in parallel with 20 cores takes extremely long to finish.
What are my options to impute this dataset preferably in a single imputation, as efficiently as possible while also accounting for the longitudinal format of the dataset?

If you model the correlation structure correctly and use full maximum likelihood methods you can with the missing at random assumption (but without assuming missing completely at random) use the analyze-all-available-data approach without imputation.

Thank you. Could you suggest some relevant literature on the implementation of this approach?

Start with https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/long
